# Show current value of SeekBarPreference

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app and I have added several SeekBarPreference elements in my settings page to work as sliders. They have different max values, and I think it's a problem that you cannot see what value you selected. So I wonder what's the best way to show the current value of SeekBarPreference in a preferences activity. Right now I think maybe the summary of the seekBarPreference-element is the best way, but I am open to other suggestions.

This is how the settings activity looks like:
[image]

Here's the code I tried so far:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

        ((SeekBarPreference) findPreference(R.id.seekRounds)).setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                final int progress = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(newValue));
                preference.setSummary(String.format("Current value: %d", progress));
            }
        });

    }
```

And currently I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'seekRounds'`.

Here's my root_preferences.xml:

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/main_settings_header">


        <SeekBarPreference
            app:key="seekRounds"
            android:title="Number of rounds"
            android:summary="This is the summary"
            android:max="2"
            android:progress="0"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
        />


    </PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Just add `app:showSeekBarValue="true"` to your `SeekBarPreference`.

Like this:

```
<SeekBarPreference
            app:key="seekRounds"
            android:title="Number of rounds"
            android:summary="This is the summary"
            android:max="2"
            app:showSeekBarValue="true"
            android:progress="0"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
        />
```